# Doubt on mathematical Logic

Tags: predicate-logic

Consider the following first order logic statement

$I)\forall x\forall yP\left ( x,y \right )$

$II)\forall x\exists yP\left ( x,y \right )$

$III)\exists x\exists yP\left ( x,y \right )$

$III)\exists x\forall yP\left ( x,y \right )$

Which one of the following is  true about $I,II,III,IV?$

$A)$ If $II)$ is true , then $III),IV)$ is true

$B)$  If $IV)$ is true , then $II),III)$ is true

$C)$ None of these

---

If I put logic then answer that I am getting $C)$ , but according to given answer $II)$ and $IV)$ has same power, So answer will be $I)$
Which one is correct?

Comment: Maybe the second III must be IV.

Comment: Probably helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225654/are-these-two-predicate-statements-equivalent-or-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your second **III)** was supposed to be **IV)**...

**(A)** If II is true, then III and IV are true.

II says that for all $x$, there exists a $y$ such that $P(x,y)$. If this is true, then III is true because III states that there exists an $x$ and $y$ such that $P(x,y)$. Well, since II says that for all $x$ there is a certain $y$ that makes this true, there certainly does exist a pair of $x$ and $y$ such that $P(x,y)$. In fact, there are as many pairs as there are $x$s. So III is true in this case.

The truth of IV does not depend on the truth of II because IV states that there exists an $x$ such that for all $y$ $P(x,y)$. To see that II and IV are different types of statements, consider the following: ‘for all people, there is a day of the year that is their birthday’ and ‘there exists a person such that all the days of the year are their birthday’. Clearly, these are totally different statements. So IV is not necessarily true in this case.

**(B)** If IV is true, then II and III are true.

IV says that there exists an $x$ such that for all $y$, $P(x,y)$. The relationship between IV and II is the same as before, so II is not necessarily true in this case.

Once again, for III to be true we just need a single pairing of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $P(x,y)$. So III is true because IV says that there is a single $x$ that can pair up with all $y$.

So, since **(A)** and **(B)** are both not true, the answer is **(C)**—none of these.