# Logical Equivalence - Difference between ∃x∀y P(x , y) and ∀y∃x P(x , y)

Tags: logic

I must be missing something here because these two statements look identical to me in regards to their truth tables. To me, ∃x∀y P(x , y) and ∀y∃x P(x , y) are logically equivalent...

a) What is the difference between the quantification
∃x∀y P (x , y) and ∀y∃x P (x , y), where P (x , y) is a
predicate?

b) Give an example of a predicate P (x , y) such that
∃x∀y P (x , y) and ∀y∃x P (x , y) have different truth
values.

Comment: Here's a start: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201051/is-the-order-of-universal-existential-quantifiers-important; and also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225654/are-these-two-predicate-statements-equivalent-or-not

Comment: Thanks, @Asaf ! I know they're out there ;-)

Comment: I encourage the next votes to close to use other links than the two already mentioned in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

a)"There exists x such that for all y ..." is much stronger than the second one.In other

words, this implies the other since in the second statement you may choose different x values

for different y values.

b)There exists x such that for all y    :$x>y$    $\hspace{17mm}  $   (F)

For every y there is x such   that      :$x>y$    $\hspace{22mm}  $   (T)